# How to handle RuntimeException after app is released

Tags: java, android, exception, runtimeexception

Below is crash report which I got from Playstore Consle

```
java.lang.RuntimeException:  
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity 
(ActivityThread.java:2756)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity 
(ActivityThread.java:2825)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12 (ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1557)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:110)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:203)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6339)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1084)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:945)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can user firebase or fabric for getting runtime application crash details.

Refer below links

https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install

Answer (score 1):

i found @sonarqube as a best to find out runtime exceptions in my application . 
Refer the link and follow the steps

> http://www.sonarsource.com/products/editions/community-edition/

its has good code coverage too 
[image]

Hope it answer your query  :)